# Как из списка ul выбрать li первого уровня?

Tags: jquery

Как из списка ul выбрать только li первого уровня ?

```js
$('.list>li').clone().appendTo('.res');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3
        <ul>
          <li>555</li>
          <li>666</li>
          <li>777</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div class="res"></div>
<hr> А хочется получить
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, это не оптимально, но я бы сделал так:

```js
temp = $('.list>li').clone();
temp.children().remove();
temp.appendTo('.res')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3
        <ul>
          <li>555</li>
          <li>666</li>
          <li>777</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: Опимально или нет , но Ваш вариант пока лучший и единственный :)

Answer (score 1):

на самом деле ты уже выбрал li первого уровня, просто свойство color - наследуется, если установишь color у ul, разница будет заметна

```js
$('.list>li').css('color', 'blue');
```

```css
ul {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3
        <ul>
          <li>555</li>
          <li>666</li>
          <li>777</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Изменил код , надеюсь так будет понятней моё желание.

Answer (score 0):

Первый элемент и многое другое вы можете сделать через псевдокалссы , как и в CSS

```
   $('.list>li:first').css('color', 'blue');
```

если вы хотите найти только первый класс лист то воспользуйтесь

```
.filter( ':first' );
```

на данный момент вы ищите все классы  list

Comment: Ваш код выделяет только первый li ОДИН. А мне нужно выделить все li первого уровня.

Comment: так вы сделали это уже